# Vertical City vs. Terrorism

Tags: architecture

Concerns over terrorism in cities are even more real and pressing than before. Since safety is a concern for every architect, every developer, every city and everyone, I want to seek advice and opinions from this community.

[Update]: I do think this question fits Worldbuilding. In order to build a vertical city, safety has to be considered. Terrorism is a huge concern now & I think it's proper to ask

"What we can do to protect vertical city citizens from attacks."

In the near future, Terrorism may not be preventable. But that's exactly why we have to talk about "building and defending a vertical city"

Comment: Possibly related: [How to protect a space elevator against terrorism](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/20311/how-to-protect-a-space-elevator-against-terrorism)

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @Zhou - this is not an anti-terrorist or security forum. It's worldbuilding. You ask a hypothetical question with well defined parameters, and other users help you brainstorm ideas. Asking "how to stop terrorism" is ridiculous. At the very least, qualify your statement: consider a building that looks like this (describe entrances, basic security, etc). Consider a terrorist with the following means and motivations (describe those). Within these technological restrictions, how would I stop him?  But i have a feeling that's not what you're looking for here ...

Comment: While I happen to be certified in Anti-Terroism/Force Protection I don't think this quite fits on world building.

Comment: While I kind of agree that it could fit on worldbuilding, I also agree with the close vote. Your question is unclear. What are you looking for exactly? Can you clarify? Also generally terrorism may take many forms, to consider all of them would be way too broad. You may consider to specify the kind of terrorist acts you have in mind. Planes? Bombs? Commandos? Gas? Bacteriologic? Etc.

Comment: That's exactly why the question is broad - because terrorism may take many forms... I am not suggesting that everyone provides their thoughts should be able to consider all of them... but any action or technology you can think of that can provide protection and defense... please consider it an open question. I am not asking for accurate answers. I am seeking thoughts and opinions. However, if the Editors who can modify my questions think it should be erased, then I'll let go. (Still trying to adjust to the community) Cheers.

Comment: It could be summarize as: how can we make buildings plane-proof ?.

Comment: Zhou, Stack Exchange isn't a forum. It uses a strict question-and-answer model, and we sometimes use the phrase "no chit-chat". This question isn't a good fit because it asks for open-ended discussion, which isn't a good fit for Stack Exchange - and vice versa.

Answer (score 3):

### The solutions are simple.

Obviously people would be concerned with terrorism and a vertical city. It's terrifying. It's good that you came to Worldbuilding to calm the people interested in making this vertical city a reality. I see two implementations to protect both against airplane attacks and smuggled explosives that should smooth out things with potential investors.

**To prevent airplane attacks:**

Build a benevolent super AI. Instruct it to identify and destroy incoming hostile or hijacked airplanes. It can do this with simple antimatter micro missiles. The armament is up to you, but antimatter will ensure that the planes are completely vaporized, keeping debris from raining down on the surrounding farmland.

**To keep bombs out:**

This is even simpler, for each person or vehicle coming into the city, disassemble them molecule by molecule with a vast swarm of nanobots. Then, after a harmless and non-invasive search of their data patterns, reassemble them inside the city walls without any explosives that may have been found during the disassembly. This has the added benefit that any people harboring thoughts on sabotage using materials inside the city can have those memories erased.

Comment: Removing memories is a pretty controversial practice. I suggest simply rematerializing them over the edge of a very tall cliff.

Comment: @AndreiROM Good point. Perhaps even bring that thought to the forefront of their mind. Just so they know why they're about to lose it.

Comment: maybe an 'Obliviate' charm? - kidding..